# How to get a reference to ListFragment's adapter and underlying data from MainActivity?

Tags: java, android

I have a ListFragment which is populated with data:

```
String list1 = {...arbitrary data...};
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1);
```

In my MainActivity I have a `changeData(String data, int position)` method that will change data of certain position in the ListFragment. How do I get that list?
I understand, first I need to get a reference to ListFragment, like this:

```
MyListFragment myListFragment = (MyListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyListFragment");
```

But what's next? Sorry, I'm a beginner in Android.

Here's my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyListFragment.Communicator, EditFragment.EditCallback{

    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MyListFragment myListFragment = new MyListFragment();
        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragContainer, myListFragment, "MyListFragment");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyListItemClick(String name, int position) {
        EditFragment editFragment = new EditFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("name", name);
        args.putInt("position", position);
        editFragment.setArguments(args);

        fragmentTransaction2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.fragContainer, editFragment);
        fragmentTransaction2.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction2.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(int position, String textUpdated) {
        //getting a reference to ListFragment:
        MyListFragment myListFragment = (MyListFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("MyListFragment");
        ArrayAdapter adapter = (ArrayAdapter) myListFragment.getListView().getAdapter();

    }
}
```

Comment: In MyListFragment create a method update and call that in MainActivity. Update can update your list.

Comment: OMG, you saved my day literally, thank you!

Comment: @javastarter, you want to call method from fragment and your method is in Activity , am I correct ?

Comment: @HirenPatel, I needed to access data in ListFragment from another fragment through interface communication. As suggested Raghunandan I just called myListFragment.changeItem and the actual implementation was held in ListFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after you update in the updateItem as you have already got the adapter. and no need to create any new methods. Here is the link for ArrayAdapter for more information.

[Array Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't have to instantiate adapter, just call the implemented method in ListFragment and set notifyDatasetChanged there.